# ZF2 Custom View helper stops execution

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm trying to create a custom View helper in zf2, I followed the instructions here which are quite straightforward:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.advanced-usage.html

but when I call `$this->SpecialPurpose()` execution stops with no error.

I ran the debugger and got the following errors:

```
Warning: Class 'Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject\PhpReferenceCompatibility' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\data\apps\http\__default__\0\MT5_0\1.0.0\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject.php on line 24

Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Stdlib\AbstractArrayObject' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\data\apps\http\__default__\0\MT5_0\1.0.0\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject.php on line 33
```

Ultimately what I want is to extend the URL Helper to make a few changes to the URLs it generates, but I haven't even been able to get this simple example to work.

Thanks

Comment: The Zend Application itself runs, only the view-helper doesn't? In that case, please provide the code for the view-helper as well as the viewHelperConfig

Comment: try this tutorial http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/zend-framework-2-create-your-custom-view-helper/

Comment: Thank You the tutorial was very helpful and the custom helper now runs as expected, I would now like to either extend the URL helper or at least call it from within my helper, but I can't seem to provide the RouterStackInterface to the helper.
How Would I go about this?

Comment: @Juan for using a helper in another helper see here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560219/create-an-instance-of-url-view-helper-in-another-viewhelper/14562376#14562376

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the module.config module where you have set up the helper
put this code:

```
'view_helpers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'SpecialPurpose' => 'your_module_name\View\Helper\SpecialPurpose',
        )
    ),
```

or in the Module.php

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
 {
    return array(
            'invokables' => array(
            'SpecialPurpose' => 'your_module_name\View\Helper\SpecialPurpose',
        )
    );
 }
```

in the reference it's quite hard to see but there is :)

```
// From within a configuration file
return array(
   'view_helpers' => array(
      'invokables' => array(
         'lowercase' => 'My\Helper\LowerCase',
         'uppercase' => 'My\Helper\UpperCase',
      ),
   ),
);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I actually had both the code in the module.config and in Module.php I'm not sure if that was the problem, I basically rewrote the whole thing from scratch and it now works as expected.

on to the second point is it possible to call the url helper from eithin this custom helper or to extend url instead of AbstractHelper?

I have tried both but get the error
`No RouteStackInterface instance provided`

I guess I need to inject the router somehow in the factory? How would I go about doing this?